# Utilizando enums em java

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

Criei um enum e preciso setar os valores no banco dessa maneira:

- Se for Receita, o valor é 0;
- Se for Despesa, o valor é 1;

Esse é o meu Enum:

```
 public enum EntryType {
   INCOME, OUTPUT;
 }
```

Na minha controller java, o tipo vem como String, pois estou pegando o value de um radio button:

```
  <input type="radio" name="income" id="radio-income" value="INCOME"
  ng-model="entry.type">
  <label for="radio-income"><span></span>Entrada</label>

  <input type="radio" name="output" id="radio-output" value="OUTPUT" 
  ng-model="entry.type">
  <label for="radio-output"><span></span>Saída</label>
```

Essa é definição do EntryType na minha entidade:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)  // Ja tentei com EnumType.Ordinal
@Column(name = "type")
private EntryType type;
```

Como faço para pegar o valor ordinal do enum para setar no banco, invés de setar a String?

Comment: Não está dando nenhum erro, só preciso setar 0 ou 1 e atualmente seto como INCOME ou OUTPUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não te recomendo utilizar o ordinal da `enum` como um identificador dela no banco de dados. Se você fizer isso, ao adicionar um novo elemento na enumeração que não seja no fim ou reordená-los, gerará uma inconsistência no seu banco de dados já que o ordinal mudará. Exemplo:

Suponha que você tenha a seguinte enumeração:

```
public enum User Role {
    
    REGISTERED_USER, ADMIN;
}
```

Nesse caso, no seu banco de dados você teria os usuário com o privilégio `REGISTERED_USER` com o valor 0 e `ADMIN` com o valor 1. Agora suponha que você adicione uma nova `UserRole`:

```
public enum UserRole {
    
    REGISTERED_USER, GUEST, ADMIN;
}
```

A partir de agora, `REGISTERED_USER` tem o valor 0, `GUEST` tem o valor 1 e `ADMIN` o valor 2. Ou seja, todos os `ADMIN` se tornaram `GUEST`!

#### Solução:

O que você pode fazer é atribuir um `id` a cada elemento e implementar um `AttributeConverter`. Dessa forma, a cada novo elemento que você adicionar, basta atribuir um novo identificador que não precisa ser sequencial.

EntryType.java

```
public enum EntryType {
    INCOME(0), 
    
    OUTPUT(1);
    
    //para uso interno
    //evita que arrays sejam criados desnecessariamente
    private static final EntryType VALUES[] = EntryType.values();
    
    private final int identificador;
    
    private EntryType(int identificador) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
    }
    
    public final int getIdentificador() {
        return identificador;
    }
    
    //Caso queira, pode retornar um optional ao invés de lançar um exceção
    public static final EntryType deIdentificador(int identificador) {
        for(EntryType et : VALUES) {
            if(et.identificador == identificador) {
                return et;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("identificador inválido: " + identificador);
    }
}
```

EntryTypeConverter

```
public final class EntryTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<EntryType, Integer> {

    @Override
    public final Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(EntryType attribute) {
        return attribute.getIdentificador();
    }

    @Override
    public final EntryType convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        return EntryType.deIdentificador(dbData);
    }

}
```

Na sua entidade:

```
@Column(name = "type")
@Convert(converter=EntryTypeConverter.class)
private EntryType type;
```

Comment: Felipe, muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo!

Mas eu tenho outra dúvida:

Como faço pra não precisar ficar setando assim no meu input do HTML?

          <input type="radio" value="OUTPUT" ng-model="entry.type">

Se eu colocar diferente de OUTPUT, já dá Bad Request. Tem alguma maneira de fazer diferente?

Comment: @GuilhermeNass Isso depende das tecnologias que você está utilizando para gerar a página HTML e para receber o objeto no lado do servidor. Talvez seja melhor criar outra pergunta já que é um tópico diferente.

Comment: Beleza, obrigado Felipe, ajudou bastante cara, consegui resolver meu problema com a sua ajuda.